# How to get to the File menu in okular

Tags: okular

I suppose this ought to be glaringly obvious, but how do I get to the File menu when I start up **okular** from the shell prompt? The screen I get has nothing resembling the usual File/Edit choices at the top; in fact it doesn't even have a choice as to whether or where to save anything if i want to extract part of the file.